# Deploying Azure Function with Personal Access Token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline for an azure function that I developed. But to publish the artifact to the azure resource, is there a way I can deploy it through PAT (like how we publish VSS extensions to the marketplace). Because the subscription belongs to another person but I want to be able to deploy. If not PAT is there an alternate way to deploy when I don't have the subscription? Thanks

Don't know if it makes sense because I am new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Service Connection to Azure Resource Manager with Service Principal in "[Manual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager)".

> Manual subscription pipeline. In this mode, you must specify the
> service principal you want to use to connect to Azure. The service
> principal specifies the resources and the access levels that will be
> available over the connection. **Use this approach when you need to
> connect to an Azure account using different credentials from those you
> are currently logged on with in Azure Pipelines or TFS.** This is also a
> useful way to maximize security and limit access.

First ask an owner of the subscription to create a Service Principal (app registration) with access to subscription, then it will be just a matter of creating service connection in DevOps (project settings -> pipelines -> service connections) with proper service principal id, key, subscription id, name etc.

[image]

You can find really good tutorial for that [here](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2019/12/12/connecting-to-azure-devops-with-a-service-principal/)

Comment: Thanks :) I have been trying to work with this. I noticed one more option called Managed identity in the service connections. I don't understand the difference between this and managed identity option. Could you please throw some light on that?